# Unable to add custom scrollbar to iframe using jQuery custom content scroller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have following code for iframe

```
<div id="demoframe" class="content">
<iframe src="mysite.com"  width="100%" height="500px" style="border:none"></iframe>
</div>
```

and following javascript code

```
<script>
 (function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $("body").mCustomScrollbar({
      theme: "dark"
    });
    $("#demoframe").mCustomScrollbar({
      theme: "dark"
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

However, only the scrollbar for body changes and not of iframe? What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It's only adding the `body` element for CSS. Add an `iframe` element.

Comment: Are you talking about `$("#demoframe").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"dark"});});` ??

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to refer to the `iframe`:

```
$("#demoframe").find('iframe').mCustomScrollbar({theme:"dark"});
```

or

```
$("#demoframe iframe").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"dark"});
```